# RoboBrowser: How to simulate asp.net image-click initiated POST

Tags: python, asp.net, robobrowser

**Question**: Given an aspx.net page whose submit is via image clicks vs. submit button, how can I simulate the image being clicked to post the form.

**Background**: I need to run some scheduled tasks against a web site (for which I cannot change the code). With RoboBrowser, I am able to log into the site and generally navigate through the pages. However, I have a case in which the user has the option to turn something on/off via clicking on one of two images. The form has a hidden submit button that auto logs-off the user (don't know why), so I cannot use browser.submit_form. I have captured the traffic generated on image click in fiddler and need to simulate it in code, but I'm not entirely certain of the best way to do that.

**System**: Python 3.4, RoboBrowser, Web site build on old aspx.net technology

**HTML** For Images that are clicked (note, RainSwitch just validates that a selection is made)

```
<input src="images\raindrop.jpg" name="imgRainSelect" type="image" id="imgRainSelect" onclick="return RainSwitch();">
<input src="images\sunsphere.jpg" name="imgAutoSelect" type="image" id="imgAutoSelect" onclick="return RainSwitch();">
```

**POST** as seen at Fiddler

```
__EVENTARGUMENT 
__EVENTTARGET   
__EVENTVALIDATION   /wEWFwLD1ZzCCgKKvpK.........
__VIEWSTATE /wEPDwULLTEyODYzNjEw.........(really long)
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR    59D0C8B1
imgAutoSelect.x 77
imgAutoSelect.y 77
rpt1$ctl00$chk  6224
rpt1$ctl00$DropDownListRainShutdownDays 0
```

**General Thoughts**:

- It feels like I should be able to click the image the same way a user would, but browser.follow_link gives me a Type error that the object is not subscriptable. I assume because the image has no a=href.
- My next thought is, *browser.open(url, method='post', data=data)* I can formulate most of the fields for data but it is a lot of work and I feel like that since this is a common operation so there must be an easier way (and I'm not even certain it will work.)
- I don't necessarily need you to write the code for me, just get me on the right track.

Thank you,

SteveJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tempted to delete the question altogether as it hasn't garnished much interest. However, I couldn't find help on this anywhere so I think it might save somebody a lot of work someday (if only a single person).

I ultimately had to formulate another post, and add the view state information in the data.

browser.open(url, method='post', data=self._get_form_post_data())

```
def _get_form_post_data(self):
    form = self.browser.get_form('Form1')
    view_state = form['__VIEWSTATE']
    generator = form['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']
    validation = form['__EVENTVALIDATION']
    data = dict(
        __EVENTTARGET="",
        __EVENTARGUMENT="",
        __VIEWSTATE=view_state.value,
        __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=generator.value,
        __EVENTVALIDATION=validation.value,
    )
    data['rpt1$ctl00$chk'] = '6224'
    data['rpt1$ctl00$DropDownListRainShutdownDays'] = '0'
    return data
```

Fiddler was a great tool to help me find what I needed to post, and so were firefox' development tools.